# "Organisation requires pin change" even after disconnecting organisation

Tags: windows, login, azure-activedirectory, pin, windows-hello

I have been using the same PIN code for Windows 11 for a long time. Recently I connected my machine to a work-account. I tried to log in with my PIN code, but I got a message that I had to change my PIN Code; it needs to be 6 characters longer.

I technically didn't need to be connected to the work account, so I disconnected it from Windows in the Settings app.

I rebooted, but my PC says I still need to change my PIN code to 6 characters.

I checked `gpedit.msc` and followed [this blog post](https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-your-organization-requires-that-you-change-your-pin) but all settings are set to `Not configured`.

I don't want to have to change my pincode, especially now that my machine isn't connected to any Azure AD joined organisations.

How can I make this message go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely once Windows itself wants the change (change already in process) you will have to follow through and change.

Change, restart, change back to 4 characters and restart again.
This work for a local account.

For a Microsoft Account, once changed to 6 digits it cannot be changed back to 4 digits.

[Length of PIN](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-set-4-digit-pin-to-log-into-windows/5d242ef1-0f0f-4079-a42f-aebdddc2ae36)

> ...   make sure you are using a local account because for Microsoft
> Account it should be a minimum of 6, try to restart the PC as well
> before trying.

Comment: Just tried this, but I can't change it back. Windows still says the pincode needs to be 6 characters long, even though it was 4 characters long initially.

Comment: I amended my post. For a local account you can change back to 4 but for a Microsoft Account the PIN length cannot go back to 4 so you are likely out of luck.